# Turning raspberry pi into a access point?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless

I currently have my raspberry pi (model B) with raspbian on there. I currently have it connected to my router wired, but I am wanting to make it just a access point where I can connect to it and back up onto it (separate from my home network I don't need internet connectivity to it)

I was hoping it would be as easy as you can do it on the openwrt routers (the tp links I tinker with)

I am using tenda 311mi nano wifi card (works right out of the box, and says on the box that it supports soft ap)

How would make it stand alone AP?

Thanks for anyone that helps me. I will keep digging and see if I can find something.

Comment: What's the output of lsusb ? IIRC correctly, they use RT5370 chipsets, and there are plenty of guides out there on how to turn a RT5370 based wifi nic into a access point.

Comment: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter

Answer (score 3):

You need to install *hostapd* and *dnsmasq* and set a static IP Address for the Pi.

*hostapd* will take care of the access point, and *dnsmasq* will be the DHCP server.

Assuming you're using Raspbian, modify `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
auto wlan0  
iface wlan0 inet static  
address 10.0.0.1  
netmask 255.255.255.0`
```

*dnsmasq* configuration file needs a whopping 2 lines:

```
interface=wlan0  
dhcp-range=10.0.0.2,10.0.0.100,12h`
```

Save the following as `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
interface=wlan0  
driver=nl80211  
ssid=RaspAP  
hw_mode=g  
channel=8  
wpa=2  
wpa_passphrase=raspiwlan  
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK  
wpa_pairwise=CCMP  
rsn_pairwise=CCMP`
```

And modify `/etc/default/hostapd.conf` and change the `daemon_conf` line to this:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

[Reference (my blog)](http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/09/how-to-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-pointrouter-part-1/)

Comment: I was just using your blog, but hostapd fails to restart and I read through your part 3a and 3b and still no luck.

Comment: Oh wow @ 2am and very tired I realised my problem(s) I had some unwanted spaces AND my password was not 8 characters...

Comment: Happens to the worst of us :D

Comment: to the worst of us? IDK if that was a insult or a comment.. D:

Comment: ..Best. sorry ! lol. too tired to even notice I made a mistake