# Toggleable Access Point

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp, static-ip

I'm following https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/ and [Turning raspberry pi into a access point?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/turning-raspberry-pi-into-a-access-point) to turn my Pi into an Access Point.  However, I also need the ability to switch back to WiFi.  I noticed that the `/etc/network/interfaces` needs to be changed to set a static ip, but I don't want to overwrite something that makes it impossible to switch back to WiFi.  Just looking for advice on best approaches and what to avoid to allow both options to work successfully. Thanks.

Comment: See https://hydrosysblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/07/rpi3-switch-between-wifi-ap-and-client/ *"I don't want to overwrite something..."* -> You can make backup copies, lol.  You can also use symlinks to switch config files, putting whatever deal into a simple script.  I don't think you have to do that in this case though.

Comment: I know I can make backup copies, my point is I don't want to configure a settings file to be compatible for one mode or another, I want to keep everything toggleable.  Taking a look at that blog.

Comment: Access point isn't working after following https://hydrosysblog.wordpress.com/rpi3-wifi-setting-new/.  I feel like there's something missing from that tutorial, all the other ones seem to have you editing the /etc/network/interfaces file and dhcpcd.conf...

Answer (score 1):

Try "***pi-ap***":  It automates configuration of a Pi 3B+ or Pi 4 running either Stretch or Buster into a WiFi Access Point.  The following link provides an overview of the solution, benefits and a download link to the Github repo:

[Automate Configuration of Pi Access Point](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101744/automate-configuration-of-pi-access-point)

You only need to edit a few default values in a centralized variables file and execute `sudo ./install.sh`, after which 3.5 minutes later a functioning AP comes out of the other end of the sausage maker.

The "***pi-ap***" solution discussed in the above link requires the Pi's `eth0` port to be assigned an IP via a DHCP-enabled port on the Internet-connected router that it's uplinked to. The only static ip that "***pi-ap***" sets is for `wlan0`.  "***pi-ap***" has no requirement for a static `eth0` IP.  However, you *could* make a persistent DHCP reservation for it in the router if you wanted to ensure its' persistency.

BTW, Interface management by ***/etc/networks/interfaces*** has been supplanted by ***/etc/dhcpcd.conf***, since (*I believe*) Raspbian Jessie.

HTH-