# Automated (Scripted) Configuration of Raspberry Pi Access Point

Tags: wifi, dhcp, access-point, hostapd, wpa-supplicant

Are there any opensource scripts/repos that automate configuring a Raspberry Pi into a Wireless Access Point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: "[pi-ap](https://github.com/f1linux/pi-ap)" a GPL 3.0 repo in Github. I configured a series of bash scripts which automate the configuration of:

- hostapd
- dnsmasq
- wpa_supplicant
- dhcpcd

...to turn a a Raspberry Pi into a Wireless Access Point.  Tested on Pi 3B+ and Pi 4 with both Raspbian ***Stretch*** and ***Buster***.

**Additional Features**:

- Fast DNS: `systemd-resolved` configured as a caching stub-resolver
- Enhanced Security: MAC Address whitelisting adds another layer of defenses
- No Subnet Calculator Required:  Any required IP calculations are done for you
- Firewalling:  A basic UFW config provided which also masquerades the eth0 interface in the NAT chain
- No Network Guru Skills Required: Fill in some values in `variables.sh` and execute `sudo ./install.sh` and you can have a working AP quite quickly
- Scripts are modular and all very well documented.
- POE Compatible:  Stick a POE Hat on it and you can emplace the AP where a 1.5 meter mains power lead won't reach

**Required Infrastructure**:

You just need a DHCP-enabled Ethernet port in a router or switch to connect the Pi's ***eth0*** port for an uplink.

My neighbour confirmed the solution worked with his BT "Home Hub" (which I understand is very common in the UK; I use a MikroTik router myself).  He just connected the Pi via its' ***eth0*** port, connected to the AP's SSID on his phone and started browsing successfully.

**Use Cases**:

"***pi-ap***" (it seemed an obvious thing to call it ;-> ) is not meant to be a replacement for an Enterprise wireless networking gear, but it suggests several obvious use cases:

- Extend WiFi coverage to dead-zones.  Internet won't reach either parts of your home/office or possibly your hammock in your backyard?!?!?
- Could take it with you to a data center if working behind a rack...
- Network Training:  This is a great training aid for teaching networking.

I guess there is a lot more that could be done, but this is a pretty good beginning. The repo can be be found at:

https://github.com/f1linux/pi-ap

**Instructions/Video Tutorials:**

- https://github.com/f1linux/pi-ap/wiki
- https://youtu.be/NUyRc2_YHzI (first 4 min of the 8 min video)

If you have an bugs to report or features to report, please do so through the Github modalities.  Hope folks find this useful- Terrence

Comment: What's the uplink? Wired (eth0) or wireless (wlan0, ap0)?

Comment: eth0.  If the Pi is plugged into a DHCP-enabled port on your router, since it's a directly connected route, you don't need to do anything with the routing.  Give it a bash.  Any bugs or features, happy to collaborate.

Comment: You should mention it. I have seen some newbees are looking for a pure WiFi repeater and confused it with a wired uplink.

Comment: @Ingo Just incorporated your feedback.  Although I guess it's an obvious thing to us, might not be so obvious thing to folks with limited networking knowledge.  Just reviewed my `README.md` file in the repo and looks like I don't expressly describe the uplink as `eth0` there, so will update it there too.  Thanks for your feedback- most appreciated! -T